# PyMongo Authentication issue

Tags: python, connection, pymongo

I get an error when trying to print the collections here.

```
import pymongo

MONGODB_URI = "mongodb+srv://myAtlasDBUser:#########@myatlasclusteredu.rgzjvt9.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)

db = client.myAtlasClusterEDU

# Print the name of the current database
print("Current Database:", db.name)

# List all collections in the current database
collections = db.list_collection_names()
print("Collections in the current database:", collections)
```

Error:  File "C:\Users\cvvis\PycharmProjects\ConnectMongoDB\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py

`your text`", line 192, in command
helpers._check_command_response(
File "C:\Users\cvvis\PycharmProjects\ConnectMongoDB\venv\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 230, in _check_command_response
raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: bad auth : authentication failed, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : authentication failed', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}

The password is rightly provided for the given user. The IP address for the current machine is also whitelisted. The user has readWriteAnyDatabase@admin permission.

Client used is: Python application.
Driver is: PyMongo 4.6.1

I tried to verify the connection string, the IP address whitelisting and the authorization permission for the current user. Everything is right.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem with my previous user account. I created a new user account with the same privileges and it worked with that user account's connection string.